# SharePoint 2019 theme on premise

Tags: theme, 2019, sharepoint-server, site-design

I wish to add a theme to a SharePoint site, that is hosted on a SharePoint 2019 Server on-premise.

I have followed these instructions as mentioned in the below link.

https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview

But this seems to work only for SharePoint Online and not for SharePoint 2019 on-premise.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Please check this, it will give you some idea. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/themes-overview

Comment: Hi @DikeshGandhi thanks for the hint. I could achieve applying composed looks to the site. But I would like to add a theme. Is this even possible for SharePoint 2019 on premise?

Comment: Kindly check second URL in my answer for creating custom themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint Site Design and Scripts are only available in Office 365 modern UI. It's not available in SharePoint 2019 on premise version.

See note in this URL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview

In SharePoint 2019 on-premise changing and applying of themes are quite same as SharePoint 2013 on-premise versions.

Please check below URLs for the same:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/themes-overview
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-composed-looks-to-brand-sharepoint-sites

**Edit by George Mavridis**:
The answer is in the comment. "It is not supported yet. But may be in future Microsoft gives compatibility for the same then it will be possible."

Comment: Hi @dikesh-gandhi, I know how to make use of composed looks. What I want to achieve is to add a look like descibed in this article here => https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview. Is this even possible for SharePoint 2019 on premise?

Comment: @GeorgeMavridis Rightnow it is not possible but may be in future Microsoft gives compatibility for the same then it will be possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.